# "To tell one from the another"

Tags: meaning

I have the following:

> Sometimes it's hard to tell one twin from another.

I've already looked up in doferent resources, but I'm still not sure about it's meaning.

I don't know whether it is "to distinguish one from another" or "tell both the first and the second twin". Translator says it's the second option whereas I found information confirming the first meaning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/tell?q=tell#tell__654)

> to distinguish one thing or person from another
>
> - **tell something**  It was hard to **tell the difference between** the two versions.
> - **tell A from B**  Can you tell Tom from his twin brother?
> - **tell A and B apart**  It's difficult to **tell them apart**.
> - **tell which, what, etc…**  The kittens look exactly alike—how can you **tell which is which**?